# Sum Values Till the Next Appearance of a Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

Thank you for coming in.

I have a table like this:

[image: table example]

And here is what I want to do: Segregated by id, I want to sum up the Val based on the condition.
For example, for id=1, I want the sum of Val till condition A firstly appear, then another sum of Val between the first A and the second A, and sum of Val between the second and the third A... The sum of Val when condition = B follows the same logic, but should not be influenced by A. Finally, each sum of Val only sums the same id.

How should I do this? I tried group by and partition by, but unable to obtain an ideal result. The ideal output would be like the Sum column in the picture.

Thank you very much.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question seems to require an ordering in the table, but no column obviously specifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a column that specifies the ordering, then you can do what you want.  SQL tables represent *unordered sets*.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

You seem to want to define groups for As and Bs.  You can do this using window functions.  This is a little strange, because you want different groupings -- a `case` expression can handle that.  Here is the idea:

```
select t.*,
       (case when condition = 'A'
             then sum(val) over (partition by id, grp_a order by <ordering col>)
             when condition = 'B'
             then sum(val) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>)
        end) as calculation
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when condition = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by <ordering col> desc) as grp_a
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! And yes, sorry I forgot to mention, the rows are ordered by date.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
WITH somatory as (SELECT id, cond, v, 
SUM(v) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as sumV
from foo),

conditional_somatory as (
select id, cond, v, sumV,
case when cond = 'A' then sumV end as somatoryA,
case when cond = 'B' then sumV end as somatoryB
from somatory
),

last_somatories as (
select id, cond, v, sumV,
SomatoryA,
max(coalesce(somatoryA,0)) over (partition by id order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as lastSomatoryA,
SomatoryB,
max(coalesce(somatoryB,0)) over (partition by id order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as lastSomatoryB
from conditional_somatory)

select id, cond, v,
case when cond = 'A' then sumV - lastSomatoryA
when cond = 'B' then sumV - lastSomatoryB 
end as somatory
from last_somatories
```

See working fiddle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b2d23b1421aa8fb45aa82ed8bad8b32